# x_scale_reverse error message with faceted plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have time series data (every 5 minutes). I have generated individual plots and added a rectangle fill to indicate the 10 minute period before a reaction took place. The time at which a reaction took place is 0 and the last point on my x-axis is when measurements began. I would like to reverse the scale so that my 10-minute block is reversed and shown at the end of the x-axis.

Here is the code I am using:

```
 p3 <- ggplot(data = HR, aes(x = Time_mins, y=HR.raw, group=ID)) + 
  geom_line() +
scale_x_reverse() +
  facet_wrap(~ID) + 
  geom_line(data = HR, aes(x = Time_mins, y=HR.mean),color = "red" ) +
  annotate("rect",xmin=0, xmax=120, ymin=0, ymax=120, alpha=.1, fill="blue")
p3
```

I get a warning message:

```
Error in -x : invalid argument to unary operator
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBH3j.png)

Comment: Pls provide a reproducible example, for instance by using `dput` on your data.

Comment: Is your x variable a character?